# How to scroll first row and last row in centre on the basis of selection in list view in android

Tags: android

I have implemented bringing selected item in centre of list view visible position but first row and last row is not coming in centre of list view .In On item click of Click List View Can anybody tell How to move first and last row moving centre

```
            int h1 = cardList.getHeight();
            int h2 = view.getHeight();
            cardList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, h1 / 2 - h2
                / 2);
```

Thanks